# jQuery function call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and remove a class within a `<span>`, but the removeClass is not working though the function is being called.

```
setInterval(changeClass,4000);

var spanId=1;

function changeClass(){
 $('#'+spanId).addClass("hilite");
 setTimeout(remove, 1000);
 spanId++;}  

function remove(){
 $('#'+spanId).removeClass("hilite");
  return true;
  }
```

Can any one tell the reason ?

How can I do this with a while loop something like this i tried all my ways but chould not get it working

```
var spanSet=4;
var spanId=1;
while(spanSet > 0)
{
changeClass();
spanSet--;
}

function changeClass(){
$('#'+spanId).addClass("hilite");
setTimeout(remove, 3000);
}

function remove(){
$('#'+spanId).removeClass("hilite");
spanId++;
return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function changeClass(){
 $('#'+spanId).addClass("hilite");
 setTimeout(remove, 1000);
 spanId++;}
```

In this code, you should execute `spanId++` in a callback function which is passed as parameter to setTimeout since JS won't halt the execution until it finishes setTimeout statement.

So your code should look like this:

```
function changeClass(){
 $('#'+spanId).addClass("hilite");
 setTimeout(remove, 1000);
}  

function remove(){
  $('#'+spanId).removeClass("hilite");
  spanId++;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : People are crazy these days.

Answer (score 5):

`spanId` is being incremented before the timeout finishes, so you are trying to remove the class from the *next* item instead of the last item.

The usual way to avoid this problem is to use a closure, but in this case it would be much simpler to move `spanId++;` to the end of the `remove` function.

The closure approach (which I don't recommend in this case as it is overly complicated compared to just moving the increment) could look like this:

```
setInterval(changeClass, 4000);
var spanId = 1;

function changeClass() {
    $('#' + spanId).addClass("hilite");
    setTimeout(
        remove(spanId), // CALL remove and pass spanId as an argument
        1000
    );
    spanId++;
}

function remove(spanId) {
    return function () { // RETURN a function from remove().
        // Note: This spanId is the local variable defined in the argument list
        //       not the one that exists in the wider scope
        $('#' + spanId).removeClass("hilite");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could update your answer with the closure method.

Answer (score 2):

You should put it that way :

```
setInterval(changeClass, 4000);
var spanId = 1;

function changeClass() {
    $('#'+spanId).addClass("hilite");
    setTimeout(remove, 1000);
}  

function remove() {
    $('#'+spanId).removeClass("hilite");
    spanId++;  // <--
    return true;
}
```

Edit : [due to Quentin suggesting to use diff tool, thank you Quentin]

I put the spanId++ at the end of remove function, so that the changeClass and remove functions are both called with the same value of spanId at each call.

Answer (score -2):

This works for me, adds some timeout control too.

```
changeClass();

function changeClass(){
    $("#container").addClass("box");
    console.log("changeClass()");
    clearTimeout(interval);
    interval = setTimeout(remove, 1000);
}

function remove(){
    $("#container").removeClass("box");
    console.log("remove()");
    clearTimeout(interval);
    interval = setInterval(changeClass,1000);
}
```

Comment: Another spot the difference answer? Oh dear. The differences are pretty awful though. You've hard coded the id of the element so it will always operate on the same element (the original code cycled through different elements), you've changed the time between the class being added, you're using clearTimeout to clear intervals and timeouts, and you're storing the timeouts/intervals from two different things in the same (global) variable - overwriting them and risking a race condition.

Comment: @Quentin - It's for illustration, not production. I guess that's how this place rolls is it... I expect a certain level of understanding of the code for them to adapt to their own.

Comment: @Darcery — Adapting code shouldn't involve undoing a big stack of unimprovements.