# while loop calling setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of `<span>` with numbered Ids, i want to add class to `<span>` with `Id=1` wait for 3 second remove class than add class to `<span id=2>` and so and so forth...

how to get this code work. `while` loop is unable to call `setTimeout` can any one help?

```
var spanSet = 4;
var spanId = 1;
while (spanSet != 0) {
    changeClass();
    spanSet--;
}

function changeClass() {
    $('#' + spanId).addClass("hilite");
    setTimeout(remove, 1000);
    spanId++;
}

function remove() {
    alert('remove');
    $('#' + spanId).removeClass("hilite");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `spanId` in the while header (instead of `spanSet`)?

Comment: this is why questions should describe what you're trying to do, and not what you think is wrong.  TJC has the right idea...

Comment: a timeout in a loop. somethings wrong logically. The spanId is not preserved

Comment: This seems to be related to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600322/function-call-not-working). Keep in mind that SO is not the place to crowd-debug/-develop your code.

Comment: updated the question with more details

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs its really cool to see so many responses in no time :-)

Comment: @srijibmandal please make your mind up!  You've accepted three different answers now!

Comment: @Alnitak :-) actually the thing is the final outcome is same but the ways are different so i liked the ways. i am new to the world of jQuery so the approaches are fascinating. is there a rule that i have to select only one to be acceptable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/PXPZW/) to see what's actually happening in you code.

Remove the `while` loop and set it up like this (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/HKdXK/)):

```
var spanId = 1;
changeClass();

function changeClass(){
 $('#'+spanId).addClass("hilite");
 spanId+=1;
 setTimeout(remove, 500);
}

function remove(){
 $('#'+(spanId-1)).removeClass("hilite");
 if (spanId<6){
   changeClass();
 }
}
```

Comment: `var spanId=1;
    
changeClass();

function changeClass(){
 $('#'+spanId).addClass("hilite");
 setTimeout(remove, 3000); //you meant 3000 I suppose?
}

function remove(){
 spanId++;
 $('#'+spanId).removeClass("hilite");
 if (spanId<3) //you can also ditch spanset and use spanId<5
   changeClass();
}`


used this way but remove function is not working

Answer (score 0):

This would be simplest with the jQuery animation functions.

This is *all* that's needed:

```
var spanId = 1;

(function hilite() {
    $('#' + spanId).addClass('hilite').delay(3000).queue(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hilite').dequeue();
        if (++spanId < 5) {
            hilite();
        }
    });
})();
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/Bs8kj/

For a more generic one which assumes nothing about the IDs, and needs no external variables, try this:

```
(function hilite(a) {
    $(a.shift()).addClass('hilite').delay(3000).queue(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hilite');
        if (a.length) {
            hilite(a);
        }
    });
})(['#1', '#2', '#3', '#4']);
```

NB: numeric IDs is an HTML5 thing.  They're also not supported by CSS.

Comment: this is better than mine. more jQuery like.